# Mocking a static methods return called with in a Method being tested in groovy

Tags: testing, groovy

I have a

```
class A {
  public static boolean isRunning() {
    if (ctx == null) { .. }
    return ctx.isRunning();
  }
}
```

I am testing a method that in the middle calls A.isRunning();

```
class B {
 public void methodToBeTested() {
   A.isRunning();
   // do somthing
 }
}
```

I want to test this in a way that when A.isRunning() is called it right away returns true and does not go initializing the context.

As class B does not have a property for type A, I am not sure what is the way to test this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine your `A.isRunning()` through metaprogramming:

```
A.metaClass.static.isRunning = { true }
```

If you run that line before your test, it will make that method always return true